# Hibernate 5.2.10.Final - javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

Tags: java, hibernate, migration

After migration from Hibernate 4.3 to 5.2 I'm getting error *javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress*. What can cause this error? Why transaction doesn't exist?

```
public class HibernateUtil {
private static StandardServiceRegistry registry;
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(HibernateUtil.class);
private static final ThreadLocal<Interceptor> threadInterceptor = new ThreadLocal<>();
private static final ThreadLocal<Session> threadSession = new ThreadLocal<>();

/**
 * Retrieves the current Session local to the thread.
 *
 * <p/>
 * If no Session is open, opens a new Session for the running thread.
 *
 * @return Session
 */
public static Session getSession() throws InfrastructureException {
    Session s = threadSession.get();
    try {
        if (s == null) {
            if (getInterceptor() != null) {
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("Using interceptor: " + getInterceptor().getClass());
                }
                s = getSessionFactory().openSession();
            } else {
                s = getSessionFactory().openSession();
            }
            threadSession.set(s);
        }
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        throw new InfrastructureException(ex);
    }
    return s;
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if (sessionFactory == null) {
        try {
            // Create registry
            registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .configure()
                    .build();

            // Create MetadataSources
            MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);

            // Create Metadata
            Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();

            // Create SessionFactory
            sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (registry != null) {
                StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
            }
        }
    }
    return sessionFactory;
}

private static Interceptor getInterceptor() {
    return threadInterceptor.get();
}
```

General method for storing objects in database (BaseDAO). Error is thrown in session.flush() line.

```
protected static void storeObject(Object object) throws DAOException {
    try {
        Session session = Helper.getHibernateSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(object);
        session.flush();
        session.beginTransaction().commit();
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        rollback();
        throw new DAOException(he);
    }
}
```

Method in UserDAO class:

```
public void save(User user) throws DAOException {
    storeObject(user);
}
```

hibernate.cf.xml

```
<session-factory>
    <!-- SQL - Settings -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
        jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?autoReconnect=true&amp;autoReconnectForPools=true
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">test</property>

    <!-- connection pool -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">5000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">180</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>

    <!-- use the C3P0 connection pool -->
    <property name="connection.provider_class">
        org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider
    </property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">managed</property>

    <!-- Don't echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>

    <!-- Validate database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>

    <!-- Mapping -->
    <mapping class="org.test.data.database.beans.User"/>

</session-factory>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
session.beginTransaction().commit();
```

starts and then immediately commits (ends) the transaction. But your `flush()` needs to happen in between. Try this instead:

```
protected static void storeObject(Object object) throws DAOException {
  Transaction tx = null;
  try {
    Session session = Helper.getHibernateSession();
    session.saveOrUpdate(object);
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.flush();
    tx.commit();
  } catch (HibernateException he) {
    if(tx != null){
      tx.rollback();
    } 
    throw new DAOException(he);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same error but all operations are something like: Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.saveOrUpdate(entityObj);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                session.getTransaction().rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }

Comment: There are some difference between use transaction implicity or directly?

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot!